# Percentage of total in PivotTable

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table, percentage

I'm in Excel 2007 and have used an SQL query to pull pass / fail data from two test rigs into a PivotTable. Below are my current / ideal outputs, please excuse the formatting of the dates!

I've tried Value Field Settings > Show values as % of column, but that doesn't work properly as it also divides the pass rate between the rigs. I've found references to changing the Parent Column, but this seems to be Excel 2010 onwards. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Current output

```
Pass Rate   Date                    
Outcome      2013-12-05 2013-12-08  2013-12-09  2013-12-10  2013-12-11
F                67         17          50          62           51 
RigOne           33         11          31          25           27
RigTwo           34          6          19          37           24
P                80         29          54          79           46
RigOne           50         21          32          42           21
RigTwo           30          8          22          37           25
Grand Total     147         46         104         141           97
```

Ideal Output

```
Pass Rate   Date                    
             2013-12-05 2013-12-08  2013-12-09  2013-12-10  2013-12-11
RigOne           %%         %%          %%          %%           %%
RigTwo           %%         %%          %%          %%           %%
Average          %%         %%          %%          %%           %%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually managed to do it by changing my SQL query to provide the inputs pnuts suggested. Once I changed the code it was pretty straightforward - I just created a calculate field for each rig to divide the number of passes by the number of tests as well as an average of the two, then formatted them as percentages. In case it's of use to anyone I've included my SQL below. Probably very clumsy, but it gives the right answer!

```
SELECT CONVERT (Date, [Stamp]) AS Date
  ,SUM(case when Pass='P' and TestRig = 'Rig 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS R1Passes
  ,SUM(case when Pass='P' and TestRig = 'Rig 2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS R2Passes
  ,SUM(case when Pass IN ('P', 'F') and TestRig = 'Rig 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS R1Tests
  ,SUM(case when Pass IN ('P', 'F') and TestRig = 'Rig 2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS R2Tests
FROM [dbase].[dbo].[tbl_Results]
where Stamp > '2013-12-01'
  and TestName = 'Finished'
GROUP BY CONVERT (Date, [Stamp])
```

Answer (score 0):

IF this is the result you would like:

[image: SO20518715 example]

then, assuming your source data is in four columns: Rig, Date, Outcome and Value:

1. Create a PT with Rig for Row Labels, Date and Outcome (top down order) for Column Labels and Sum of Value for Σ Values.
2. In Quick Menu, PivotTable Options..., Totals & Filters uncheck Show grand totals for rows.
3. Select a `Fail` and in PivotTable Tools > Options > Tools - Formulas, Calculated Item... add Average for Name: and in Formula: put `=Pass/(Pass +Fail )`.
4. Select Average and Sort A to Z.
5. In a row below Grand Total calculate weighted average pass rate under each Date's Average.
6. Set font color for Grand Total row to match fill colour.
7. Hide Pass/Fail columns and Row Labels row.
8. Change cells to Pass Rate and Date.
9. Format to suit.

Comment: Hi!
Unfortunately it's nothing that simple - my columns are Rig, Date, and Outcome, the outcome is either P or F. Unfortunately this is part of the coding of the test rigs so not something within my control. I've been trying to use COUNT(Pass) in a calculated field to give me a total, and COUNTIF (Pass = "P") to give me a count of pass, and then use another calculated field to give me my percentage... However, COUNT(Pass) always gives me a result of 1, and COUNTIF doesn't seem to be a valid in a calculated field.